# Populate PDF Fields via XML

Tags: xml, pdf

I am developing a simple digital guest registry for a small business. I started with a simple jot form since they just need to collect the data. I then exported the data into an Excel sheet and now i need to get the data from that excel sheet into a PDF form that I built. It has been pre formatted in the layout that the customer needs, however when i go to use XML to get the data from the excel sheet to the PDF, i am not seeing any data fields that can be populated. I am beating my head against a wall to figure out how to get this data to populate the PDF form. Any help or guidance would be super helpful.

I cannot find out why the PDF Fields are not being able to be populated via XML. I can see all the data in the Excel XML. I have placed the PDF XML Code below along with the screenshot of the fields that are in the PDF.[Screenshot of the PDF with field descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64oRB.png)

This is the PDF XML

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<!--  Created from PDF via Acrobat SaveAsXML  -->
<!--  Mapping Table version: 28-February-2003  -->
<TaggedPDF-doc>
<?xpacket begin='' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
<?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 9.1-c001 79.675d0f7, 2023/06/11-19:21:16 ">
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<rdf:Description xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/" xmlns:adhocwf="http://ns.adobe.com/AcrobatAdhocWorkflow/1.0/" rdf:about="">
<xmp:ModifyDate>2024-01-18T14:29:37-06:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
<xmp:CreateDate>2024-01-08T10:20:51-06:00</xmp:CreateDate>
<xmp:MetadataDate>2024-01-18T14:29:37-06:00</xmp:MetadataDate>
<xmp:CreatorTool>Adobe Acrobat Pro (32-bit) 23.8.20458</xmp:CreatorTool>
<dc:format>xml</dc:format>
<xmpMM:DocumentID>uuid:6a46ae45-d9cc-4498-ba37-66a3c1dde9bb</xmpMM:DocumentID>
<xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:9eab79c9-9094-4043-a7c5-93dea53245d4</xmpMM:InstanceID>
<pdf:Producer>Adobe Acrobat Pro (32-bit) 23.8.20458</pdf:Producer>
<adhocwf:state>1</adhocwf:state>
<adhocwf:version>1.1</adhocwf:version>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
<?xpacket end="w"?>
<?xpacket end='r'?>
<bookmark-tree>
<bookmark title="Blank Page">
<destination structID="LinkTarget_527"/>
</bookmark>
</bookmark-tree>
<Figure id="LinkTarget_527">
<ImageData src="images/Test 2_img_0.jpg"/>
Relatives & Friends
</Figure>
<P>
<Form/>
</P>
<P/>
<P>e </P>
</TaggedPDF-doc>
```